# PDFs looking different in Yosemite Preview.app

Tags: pdf, preview, macos, bug

I've just installed Yosemite on my iMac and noticed that my PDF files viewed with the Preview.app don't look the same as in Mavericks. If I view the PDF files directly in Safari, all looks like it should. Against this in the Preview.app it looks kinda trashy.

Is there anyone who can confirm this? And if it's so, how can I make Preview.app show the PDFs like Safari does?

[image]

Comment: @Buscar You can't 'adjust colour' for a PDF.

Comment: Found the PDF and tried it on my own machine. @srolle you are right that Preview and Safari are rendering the PDF differently. I don't think it is a different font though. It just looks slightly different in the way they are rendering the PDF. It does seem to be Preview that is doing something different though. Safari, Chrome and Firefox (which all use different engines to render PDFs) all look roughly the same, to my eyes anyway.

Comment: @AlistairMcMillan You're right, in safari, chrome and firefox it looks the same to me. But the different rendering of Preview isn't specific to the one pdf file seen in the screenshot (it's just an example), it's related to all pdf files. And viewing the PDF files with Safari or Chrome henceforth isn't a real solution for me. :( Hope there's a possibility to change the pdf rendering in Preview to the one from Mavericks.

Comment: I don't know why I am forbidden from posting an answer (I have more than 10 reputations), but a guy pointing out to me that it appears to be a "disappointing change of font anti-aliasing algorithm." He zoomed in the screenshots of same pdf viewed in OSX 10.10 & 10.8 and found that in 10.10 the font shade becomes grey rather than full-color: http://imgur.com/a/oZEnZ Apparently this is something only Apple can fix.

Comment: This bug has been reported on Apple Support Communities (see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6608276) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6607274)). See also the [reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/2joxlh/os_x_yosemite_1010_bug_thread/cleisr8).

Comment: The difference is that Preview doesn't use LCD font smoothing (subpixel rendering) in 10.10 even if LCD font smoothing is enabled from System Preferences.

Comment: In my opinion, this is a form of planned obsolescence. While sub-pixel smoothing was a cool trick to kinda multiply by 3 the horizontal resolution of LCD display, nowadays it becomes less useful due to the increasing resolution of monitors. It is pointless to do this on retina displays, and you can also notice that it has never been done on iPads (also maybe due to the fact that the screen can be rotated). IMO, Yosemite implies recent hardware, ie high DPI screens.

Comment: NOT fixed in 10.10.1 ...

Comment: NOT fixed in 10.10.3. Getting frustrating.

Comment: @level1807, I believe you meant 10.10.2?

Comment: @level1907 Same here. Actually I'm wondering if Apple even cares about the problem, because it seems only to affect non-Retina-users.

Comment: Has anyone updated to the newest 10.10.3 and tested Preview?

Comment: @LeoFang Yes, finally it's fixed in 10.10.3! :)

Comment: @JohnnyDrama No. I still have this issue in 10.10.5.

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting isolation, what if you use Adobe Reader, Is the rendering clear using a dedicated software ?

**edit :** It appears that Preview is no longer using subpixel rendering in Yosemite.
There is no fix for now, Apple will probably enable this in a next OS X update as the problem is quite documented over the Web

Comment: Frankly I would downvote this answer if I could. First of all, the link you provided was issued this May, which is apparently not for the problem we are concerning. Secondly, it has been thoroughly discussed in the comments and other linked posts that font smoothing is not used by the Yosemite Preview.app and that subpixel rendering is disabled. While it is nice that more and more people notice this bug, I do hope that an answer should be posted before doing some homework.

Comment: You must have missed my edit (you know the part in **bold**) that states that you will not find a solution to this, unless someone or Apple decides to recompile Preview.app to use subpixel rendering.

Comment: I removed the upper part, so it is now more clear