# Font smoothing for pdf files in OSX Yosemite Safari vs Skim

Tags: pdf, macos, latex, skim

I produce a lot of pdf files using LaTeX and thus, I also read a lot of such files. After the update to OS X 10.10 the fonts are not smooth anymore. However, Safari seems to handle it much better than Skim (see screenshot for comparison).

The option "Use LCD font smoothing when available" is enabled; without it, the texts are almost unreadable. Anyone has any clue how to make the font looking better?

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTSIi.jpg) :

[image]

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfhip.png) (left quick preview [spacebar], right Skim):

[image]

Hardware: I use non-retina MacBook Pro 2011 + Fujitsu 27" LCD attached with dual-head DVI.

Comment: This is happening with non-Retina displays in general (including mine). There's a [thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/skim-app/mailman/skim-app-users/thread/D9EC92CC-86CF-4D58-9718-53E8070291F1%40mac.com/) in the Skim users mailing list where the developer says that this is a PDFKit bug and he can't do anything about it.

Comment: Thanks dfan. Could you - Alex Pigeon - remove your edits, so that people can see the screenshots in full size?

Comment: This issue has been confirmed as a bug and is a duplicate of [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151200/) and [this](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151995/) post. This bug is reported [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6608276) and [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6607274) on Apple Support Communities.

Comment: Piotr, to tag someone you should do this: @AlexisPigeon.

Comment: @Piotr Even better : I've added links to the fullscreen images!

Comment: Thank you Leo and Alexis. We need to loudly shout about any bugs that disturb in the work, so that Apple knows where is the priority in solving them (for sure there are also many others).

Answer (score 1):

This bug appears to be fixed in 10.10.3.

I can confirm (with Pixie) the rendering is the same in Preview, Skim, and QuickLook, at least with subpixel rendering forced to 2.